# Could not convert double to string

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I've been working on a program that calculates the volume of a box, using classes to help me understand how to use classes. As part of the program I want to convert my objects length,width and height into a string to display the dimensions of the box. When I run the code from my main file it crashes. When I run it from the class file I get "could not convert Box::length from double to std::string. How can I fix the conversion error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Box
{
    public:
        double length;//length of the box
        double height;//height of the box
        double width;//with of the box

        Box(): length(1), height(1), width(1){}

        //Parameterized Constructor
        Box(double length, double width, double height);


        double getVolume(void);

        //Mutators
        void setLength(double leng);
        void setWidth(double wid);
        void setHeight(double hei);
        //Acessors
        string toString() const;
        string getLength(); 
        string getWidth();
        string getHeight();
};//end class   

//member function definitions

    double Box::getVolume(void)//get volume will cal and output the volume when called
    {
        return length * width * height;
    }
    void Box::setLength(double leng)
    {
        const double MIN_LENGTH = 0.1;//constants for min/max for range check and out_of_range exception
        const double MAX_LENGTH = 99;
        if (length > MAX_LENGTH || length < MIN_LENGTH)
        {
            stringstream strOut;//declare string stream

            strOut << "Length is out of range. Length must be between" << MIN_LENGTH << " and " << MAX_LENGTH << ".";//error msg
            throw out_of_range(strOut.str());
        }
        else
        {
            length = leng;// if length is within range, store it 
        }
    }
    string Box::getLength()
    {
        return length;
    }
    void Box::setWidth(double wid)
    {
        const double MIN_WIDTH = 0.1;//constants for min/max for range check and out_of_range exception
        const double MAX_WIDTH = 99;
        if (length > MAX_WIDTH || length < MIN_WIDTH)
        {
            stringstream strOut;//declare string stream

            strOut << "Width is out of range. Width must be between" << MIN_WIDTH << " and " << MAX_WIDTH << ".";//error msg
            throw out_of_range(strOut.str());
        }
        else
        {
            width = wid;// width is in range, store it
        }
    }   

    string Box::getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }
    void Box::setHeight(double hei)
    {
        const double MIN_HEIGHT = 0.1;//constants for min/max for range check and out_of_range exception
        const double MAX_HEIGHT = 99;
        if (length > MAX_HEIGHT || length < MIN_HEIGHT)
        {
            stringstream strOut;//declare string stream

            strOut << "Height is out of range. Height must be between" << MIN_HEIGHT << " and " << MAX_HEIGHT << ".";//error msg
            throw out_of_range(strOut.str());
        }
        else
        {
            height = hei;// height is in range, store it
        }
    }   
    string Box::getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }
    string Box::toString() const
    {
        stringstream strOut;
        strOut << "Length: " << getLength() << endl
        << "Width: " << getWidth() << endl <<
        "Height: " << getHeight() << endl;
        return strOut;
    }
```

Comment: what?  that makes no sense.  You can't run the code from the class file.  "could not convert Box::length from double to std::string" can't possibly be an error message when you run.  Looks like a type mismatch compiler error, which would say something like "cannot convert Box::length from double to std::string".

Comment: didnt mean run, meant compile to see that there were no errors

Comment: Don't output the error to the string where the value will be `strOut << "Height is out of..."`. That's what exceptions are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class definition says getLength() will return a string, however your getLength() function actually returns width, which is a double. You probably meant to convert length to a string before you return it.

You could use the to_string() function in the string library, and change your getLength() to

```
return to_string(length)
```

Comment: I changed the return statements, should I also be changing the original declarations, because it says "to_string was not declared in this scope".

Comment: you should insert #include <string> at the top, since to_string is in the string library

Comment: Also, just a bit of advice: For future reference, getWidth() should return a double, since width is double. Having some consistency in your code is a good practice. You should either define a new function, getWidthAsString() to return a string, or, in your main function itself, use to_string to convert the getWidth() return value to a string.

Comment: Wait never mind. You can fix your error by compiling with the -std=c++11 option since to_string was not available before C++11.

Answer (score 1):

This compile error is occurring at the return statements of your getWidth, getHeight, getLength functions. This is because the you declared them to return a string but instead returned a width, height, and length which are doubles. The compiler sees that there is no automatic conversion from double to string.

To fix this you only need to fix the return type of the function from string to double:

```
double getLength(); 
double getWidth();
double getHeight();
```

I noticed one more error:

```
doubletostring.cpp:104:25: error: reference to non-static member function must be called
strOut << "Length: " << getLength << endl
```

And similar errors in the toString method. Simply convert them to function calls by adding `()` at the end:

```
strOut << "Length: " << getLength() << endl
```

Comment: I changed function declarations to string getWidth(); etc. still gives the "could not convert"

Comment: Upon closer look there are actually a bunch of small errors. For example, stringstream is different from string, so toString should return `strOut.str()`. Also all your getter functions, including getVolume() should be const. I just compiled and ran the code this way.

Comment: Also, did you change both the function declaration and the function definition to the same return type? As in, does the top of the file have `double getWidth();` and later `double Box::getWidth() { return width }`. They should match.